Instability of the components in the Matter JS engine
I am simulating a snooker game via JavaScript using the P5 and Matter JS, I'm almost done but I'm having trouble with some of the ball behaviors.
I added all the balls to the engine world in Matter JS and they work properly, but when a colored ball enters a slot it has to go back to its original place.
I did this by making the holes static, and using the 'collisionStart' event I would return the ball to its place when a colored ball collided with a hole.
The problem is that the ball returns to its place correctly but it still retains some movement which makes it move.
Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {

        const pairs = event.pairs;

        pairs.forEach((pair) => {

            const bodyA = pair.bodyA;
            const bodyB = pair.bodyB;

            for (let i = 0; i < this.coloredBallsInfo.length; i++) {

                if ((bodyA.label === this.coloredBallsInfo[i][0] && bodyB.label === 'pocket') ||
                    (bodyB.label === this.coloredBallsInfo[i][0] && bodyA.label === 'pocket')) {

                    Matter.Body.setPosition(this.coloredBalls[i], { x:this.coloredBallsInfo[i][1],
                                                                    y:this.coloredBallsInfo[i][2] });

                    Matter.Body.setSpeed(this.coloredBalls[i], 0);

                    Matter.Body.setVelocity(this.coloredBalls[i], { x: 0, y: 0 });

                    Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(this.coloredBalls[i], 0); 
                }
            }
        });
    });

I added all the functions that reset the speed and acceleration to zero but there is still some slight movement.

Its going to be very hard, nay impossible, to debug this just from a vague description of the problem. Can you please provide enough code to produce a working example of the problem - ideally using the SO snippet editor.

Thank you, the problem is that the code is for a project within a university course, so I will not be able to publish the full code at the moment.

Without the full code (actually a [mcve]), it's extremely difficult to help. Did you try deleting the body and recreating it in the origin? This should remove all velocity/acceleration/etc.
